# HtmlUnit NoSuchFieldError: No static field INSTANCE of type Lorg/apache/http/conn/ssl/AllowAllHostnameVerifier

Tags: android, kotlin, htmlunit

After looking at a lot of answers none of them helped me :/
I'm trying to use the latest version of htmlunit in android but I keep getting an error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No static field INSTANCE of type Lorg/apache/http/conn/ssl/AllowAllHostnameVerifier; in class Lorg/apache/http/conn/ssl/AllowAllHostnameVerifier; or its superclasses (declaration of 'org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AllowAllHostnameVerifier' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar!classes4.dex)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.<clinit>(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:149)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.httpclient.HtmlUnitSSLConnectionSocketFactory.buildSSLSocketFactory(HtmlUnitSSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:89)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.HttpWebConnection.configureHttpsScheme(HttpWebConnection.java:626)
```

Here is my gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'java-library'
apply plugin: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm'

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$rootProject.kotlin"

    implementation 'net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:2.34.1'

    testImplementation "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:$rootProject.junit"
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
```

I get the part where HtmlUnit is using something that was removed in recent versions. But how do I fix this?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: not sure if this answers your question but someone informed me recently (on a JSoup question) that htmlunit doesnt work with Android. No idea why - perhaps they're wrong. But Jsoup does work with android and offers similar but simpler functionality.

Comment: The thing is that there some websites where the values displayed are updated via serviceworkers or after running JS functions and JSoup doesn't handle that. Do you have any suggestion for this issue?

Comment: You’d have to figure out what’s going on under the hood to make very specific requests. It’s is doable but can be hard, time consuming work

Comment: Many people are facing the same issue. https://github.com/HtmlUnit/htmlunit/issues/444

Answer (score 1):

There core reason for this error is a class version clash between HtmlUnit (using HttpClient) and and the version of the HttpClient partly integrated inside the android jdk.

See https://github.com/HtmlUnit/htmlunit/issues/444 for more.

The new htmlunit-android project https://github.com/HtmlUnit/htmlunit-android project fixes this.

Please try and report any problems on github.